# How to GroupBy nullable DateTimeOffset property using EF Core 6

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Entity class:

```cs
public class Transaction
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset? TransactAt { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I want group by `UserId` and `TransactAt.Date` so here is how I query:

```cs
var transactions = await dbContext.Transactions
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x.TransactAt.HasValue
        && x.TransactAt.Value.Date < DateTime.Today.Date)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.TransactAt.Value.Date })
    .Select(m => new TransactionWithoutInvoiceModel
    {
        UserId = m.Key.UserId,
        TransactionIds = m.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(),
        Amounts = m.Select(x => x.Amount).ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

But I get a compiler error:

> Nullable value type may be null. csharp(CS8269)

So, I tried:

```cs
GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId, x.TransactAt?.Date })
```

But then I get another error:

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator. csharp(CS8072)

Demo data:

```bash
Transactions

Id      UserId      Amount      TransactAt
------------------------------------------------------
1       123         100         2022-12-26 01:02:03+00
2       123         200         2022-12-26 01:05:03+00
3       123         300         2022-12-26 01:08:03+00
4       123         400         2022-12-26 01:10:03+00
5       123         500         2022-12-27 01:02:03+00
6       456         100         2022-12-26 01:02:03+00
7       456         200         2022-12-26 01:02:03+00
```

The grouped result I expect is like:

```json
[
   {
      // User 123 transactions on 2022-12-26
      "UserId":123,
      "TransactionIds":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4
      ],
      "Amounts":[
         100,
         200,
         300,
         400
      ]
   },
   {
      // User 123 transactions no 2022-12-27
      "UserId":123,
      "TransactionIds":[
         5
      ],
      "Amounts":[
         500
      ]
   },
   {
      "UserId":456,
      "TransactionIds":[
         6,
         7
      ],
      "Amounts":[
         100,
         200
      ]
   }
]
```

Environment:

- .NET SDK `6.0.400`
- PostgreSQL `13.3`
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL `6.0.7`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GroupBy(x => new { x.UserId,(x.TransactAt!=null ? x.TransactAt.Date : default)})

// here default is the default DateTimeOffset value in case of null or you can use String.Empty
```

Comment: This compiled okay, but throws at run time:

Unable to translate a collection subquery in a projection since either parent or the subquery doesn't project necessary information required to uniquely identify it and correctly generate results on the client side. This can happen when trying to correlate on keyless entity type. This can also happen for some cases of projection before 'Distinct' or some shapes of grouping key in case of 'GroupBy'. These should either contain all key properties of the entity that the operation is applied on, or only contain simple property access expressions.